# Java - Image Processing Package

Tags: java, image, package

I'm trying to make a maths inspired background image for my computer. What I've decided to do is a visualization of the Collatz Conjecture (video for explanation of the mathematical problem and method of visualization: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqKpkdRRLZw&t=224s). Now I know that there are tons of different cool high resolution images on this very topic but half of the fun in it is making it myself.

So on to the problem. The tree structure is already implemented and took a couple of hours (I'm not a great Java programmer) so what I want to do now is create the actual image. I'm in essence looking for a simple image processing package or even some image processing software that can read information from a .txt file and will let me tell it what to do with it. I want to be able to draw lines, assign widths and colors and chose background colors etc. I had thoughts of doing the entire thing in Matlab instead so if you recommend I do it there I can do that as well. Also python is an option. But to clarify the problem isn't the actual making of the tree but rather the visualization and making a pretty image. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I just found this (http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html). It seems to do what I want. Is it any good?